# Flask Blueprint structure

Tags: python, flask

I am using Blueprints to separate my `api`, `admin` and `authentication`, but in my API I want to separate `users`, `groups` and `files` for a better structure instead of just one `routes` file.

So my question is: is it possible to create a blueprint inside a blueprint?

Or is there a better solution to accomplish my structure needs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested Blueprints in Flask?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003178/nested-blueprints-in-flask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to "nest" them to achieve what you want. You just need to create the `Blueprint` instance in one module and then import that instance in the multiple route files that you have for that blueprint.

```
# api/blueprint.py
from flask import Blueprint
bp = Blueprint(__name__, __name__)

# api/users.py
from .blueprint import bp
@bp.route(...)

# api/groups.py
from .blueprint import bp
@bp.route(...)
```