# Flask Get blueprint's name from inside another blueprint

Tags: python, flask

There are test123.html inside templates/blue folder

```
# blueprint 1
from flask import Blueprint
from echo.__init__ import echo_template

blue = Blueprint('blue', __name__)

@page.route('/test123')
def test():
    return echo_template('test123', blue.name)

# blueprint 2 (for template helper)
from flask import render_template, Blueprint

echo = Blueprint('echo', __name__)

def echo_template(template_name, blue_name, **context):
    file_name = blue_name + '/' + template_name + '.html'
    return render_template(file_name, **context)
```

I can call like:

```
echo_template('name', 'blue_name', a="a")
```

but i want to call it like below

```
echo_template('name', a="a")
```

I need a way to get blueprints name from echo blurprints and add automaticlly to function

Comment: possibly related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003178/nested-blueprints-in-flask

Comment: so i can put my template files inside templates/blueprintname/template_name.html