# Nestable Blueprint not working

Tags: python, design-patterns, flask

I would like to use Blueprint nesting so that similar blueprints can have similar `@similar.before_request`, etc (along with nice url name spacing).

I am aware that flask doesnt native support this feature.

However, [this issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/593) mentions a way to do it:

```python
class NestableBlueprint(Blueprint):
    """
    Hacking in support for nesting blueprints, until hopefully https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/593 will be resolved
    """

    def register_blueprint(self, blueprint, **options):
        def deferred(state):
            url_prefix = (state.url_prefix or u"") + (options.get('url_prefix', blueprint.url_prefix) or u"")
            if 'url_prefix' in options:
                del options['url_prefix']

            state.app.register_blueprint(blueprint, url_prefix=url_prefix, **options)
        self.record(deferred)
```

Trying the above fails to work, and gives me 404.

I have a file, which defines a blueprint like :

```python
base_blueprint = Blueprint("BASE", __name__, url_prefix='/v0.1')
```

At the bottom, I have :

```python
from .Admin import admin_base_blueprint
admin_base_blueprint.register_blueprint(base_blueprint,
                                        url_prefix='/admin')
```

And Admin.py is defined as:

```python
admin_base_blueprint = NestableBlueprint('admin', __name__)


@admin_base_blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def admin_echo_time():
    """
    Just a function to echo current time.
    May be useful for testing if servers are up.
    :return: current date
    """

    return datetime.now()
```

When I try to visit `GET /v0.1/admin`, it give me a 404.

I also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/36326234/2670775. In this case, I am able to get url name spacing to work , but blueprint functions like before_request dont get called.

**my flask version is 0.12.2**